# Binary Heap - inserting order

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary, heap

Does inserting order affects the structure of binary heap? I mean, is it possible to get a little different parent-children relations when inserting the same elements in different orders,
for example:

> 20 6 3 5 7 8 16 10 (inserting order #1) and 6 3 20 10 16 3 7 5 (inserting order #2)

or the final result should always be the same?

Comment: A binary heap (max or min-heap), so basically inserting in a different order might change the positions of the elements but in the same level i.e it cannot go to another level of the tree, because that violates the property of min/max-heap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A heap can store a given collection of values in different ways. For instance, if the heap happens to be a perfect binary tree, then you can swap any subtree with its sibling subtree without violating the heap property.

For example, if the data collection has the values 1, 2 and 3, there are 2 possible heaps that can represent that data set:

```
         1                   1
        / \                 / \
       2   3               3   2
```

The first will be the result when 2 is inserted *before* 3, and the second heap will be the result when 2 is inserted *after* 3.

If we look at an input with four values (e.g. 1, 2, 3 and 4), we can represent that in four heaps:

```
          1            1           1           1
         / \          / \         / \         / \
        2   3        2   4       3   2       4   2
       /            /           /           /
      4            3           4           3
```

Again, the order of insertion will determine which of those four heaps will be the end result.

Answer (score 1):

If you imagine the sequences 1 1 1 1 2 2 and 1 1 2 1 1 2, you should end up with different heaps.

```
    1              versus          1
 1     1                        1     2
1 2   2                        1 1   2
```